# How to get the redirect link of an anchor tag which is built using JavaScript?

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I have a link which redirects to an external website... I want to find out what is the final URL that the link redirects to. I tried:

```
requests.get("link.which.redirects.and.has.dynamic.js.code.com")
```

But I could not get the final redirected URL as it is built dynamically... I am not sure exactly what happens but there are some JavaScript code involved in loading of the page and the final result is a redirect to an external page.

So instead I tried `Selenium` and `ChromeDriverManager`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    def parse(self, response):
        link = "link.which.redirects.and.has.dynamic.js.code.com"
        self.driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(1) # without this wait, driver.current_url is not the final redirect
        url = self.driver.current_url
```

The code above loads the entire page, in order to get the redirect URL, is there a more efficient way to get the redirect URL?

Comment: Can you share what `requests.get("link.which.redirects.and.has.dynamic.js.code.com").url` gives you?

Comment: Got it. You should delete it now I think.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the final like you can use the following code:

```py
import time
import requests

website = requests.get("link.which.redirects.and.has.dynamic.js.code.com", time.sleep(5))

print(website.url) # To see final URL
print(website.history) # To see from where it was the redirection codes
print(website.is_redirect) # Was it redirected 
print(website.is_permanent_redirect) # Is it permanently redirected
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I explained in the question, I have tried `requests.get("URL")` but since the result is built using js code, I am not able to see the final result using `requests.get`... that's when you need a headless browser to get the final result.

Comment: I tried adding 5 seconds wait, and it does not load the final redirected url...